# Bad file descriptor error - read, when using nohup to run server in background of ubuntu box

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, server, nohup

I get this error appended to nohup.out every time I try to use make serve with the nohup command.

### The nohup command I run

```
codio@anita-doctor:~/workspace/Introduction-to-Data-Science/IntroBook$ nohup make serve &
[1] 2201
codio@anita-doctor:~/workspace/Introduction-to-Data-Science/IntroBook$ nohup: ignoring input and 
appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```

---

My program server works fine using the normal make serve without nohup. I am trying to host my server in the background using nohup but when I perform the above code I get the below error.

### The error appended to nohup.out

```
[0m19:01:07 - INFO - Bye bye...
bundle exec guard
Configuration file: _config.yml
23:06:19 - INFO - Jekyll [33mbuilding... [0m
23:06:21 - INFO - Jekyll [32mbuild completed in 1.67s [0m/home/codio/workspace/Introduction-to- 
Data-Science/IntroBook → _site
23:06:21 - INFO - Jekyll watching and serving using jekyll at 0.0.0.0:4000/jupyter-book
23:06:21 - INFO - Jekyll watching
23:06:21 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
23:06:21 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/codio/workspace/Introduction-to-Data- 
Science/IntroBook'
[0G/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:279: 
warning: method Pry#input_array is deprecated. Use Pry#input_ring instead
[1] guard(main)> Error: Bad file descriptor - read
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `block in 
input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:113:in 
`interruptible_region'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:199:in `input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:185:in `block in read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:130:in `handle_read_errors'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:171:in `read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in 
`__with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in 
`with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:102:in 
`block (2 levels) in _switch_to_pry'
[1] guard(main)> Error: Bad file descriptor - read
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `block in 
input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:113:in 
`interruptible_region'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:199:in `input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:185:in `block in read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:130:in `handle_read_errors'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:171:in `read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in 
`__with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in 
`with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:102:in 
`block (2 levels) in _switch_to_pry'
[1] guard(main)> Error: Bad file descriptor - read
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `block in 
input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:113:in 
`interruptible_region'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:199:in `input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:185:in `block in read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:130:in `handle_read_errors'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:171:in `read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in 
`__with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in 
`with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:102:in 
`block (2 levels) in _switch_to_pry'
[1] guard(main)> Error: Bad file descriptor - read
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `block in 
input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:113:in 
`interruptible_region'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:199:in `input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:185:in `block in read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:130:in `handle_read_errors'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:171:in `read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in 
`__with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in 
`with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:102:in 
`block (2 levels) in _switch_to_pry'
[1] guard(main)> Error: Bad file descriptor - read
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:200:in `block in 
input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:113:in 
`interruptible_region'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:199:in `input_readline'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:185:in `block in read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:130:in `handle_read_errors'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:171:in `read_line'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:59:in 
`__with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:77:in 
`with_ownership'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:200:in `start'
/home/codio/anaconda/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/guard-2.14.2/lib/guard/jobs/pry_wrapper.rb:102:in 
`block (2 levels) in _switch_to_pry'
FATAL: Pry failed to get user input using `Readline`.
To fix this you may be able to pass input and output file descriptors to pry directly. e.g.
   Pry.config.input = STDIN
   Pry.config.output = STDOUT
   binding.pry

[0m    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/jupyter-book/
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
]2;

[0m23:06:21 - INFO - Bye bye...
```

---

Any help would be appreciated as it is essential to my project that I am able to host in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run `pry` inside of your application as the errors seem related.  Try to remove or comment out any occurance of `binding.pry` and anywhere you may have included or required pry such as in Gemfile, or if you have any `require 'pry'` in anything.

Then try your command again to see if this works.